# mailerを実装しているのですが、メールが送れない状態にあります。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

私は、今現在、mailerを使い、あるページに移動すると、メールが送信されるようにしたいと考えています。しかし、controllerの設定がうまくできていないこともあり、送ることができない状態にあります。もしわかる方がいらしたら、教えていただきたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

controller/tourist/done.controller.rb

```
def done
  TouristMailer.tourist_payment_mail(self).deliver_now
end
```

config/environment/development.rb

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
     port:                  587,
     domain:               'smtp.gmail.com',
     user_name:            '******@gmail.com',
     password:             '**********',
     authentication:       'plain',
     enable_starttls_auto:  true
   }
```

application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "******@gmail.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

model/tourist.rb

```
class Tourist < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  after_create :send_welcome_mail

  def send_welcome_mail
     TouristMailer.tourist_welcome_mail(self).deliver_now
  end

  def tourist_payment_mail
     TouristMailer.tourist_payment_mail(self).deliver_now
  end

  has_many :guiders

  devise   :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

tourist_mailer.rb

```
class TouristMailer < ApplicationMailer
 default from: '<*******:@gmail.com>'

 def tourist_payment_mail(tourist)
     @tourist = tourist
     mail(
         from: '<******@gmail.com>',
         to:   '<#{@tourist.email}>',
         subject: 'お問い合わせ'
         )
 end

end
```

tourist_payment_mail.html.erb

```
<html lang="ja">
 <head>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <h2><%= @tourist %> 様</h2>
   <hr />
   <p>
     こんにちは！ <%= @tourist %>さん！</p>
   <hr />
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージに

```
undefined method `email` for #<TouristsController:xxxxxxxxxxxxx>
```

と出ていますので`Tourist`モデルではなく`TouristsCOntroller`自体を渡してしまっていることがわかります。

おそらく`controller/tourist/done.controller.rb`で`TouristsController`を定義してるため、`self`で`TouristsController`自体が参照されてしまっています。

`Tourist`モデルのどこかで`payment`に関する処理があると思いますので、その処理と紐付いた所から該当の`Tourist`インスタンスを呼び出してメールを作成してください。

できればプロジェクトのフォルダ構造がRailsの標準に沿わないよくわからないものになっていますので一度Ruby on Rails Guideなどを通して読まれることをおすすめします。

Comment: modelを呼び出したいのですが、呼び出し方が分かりません。外部の決済のページから自分のページに戻ってきた時に、メールを送ることが可能でしょうか？もし可能であれば、どこのエリアを学ぶ必要があるのでしょうか?Ruby on Rails Guideを読んでみます！！

Comment: 外部の決済処理を呼び出した時に返り値で支払い成功・失敗の情報が含まれてるでしょうから、そこから呼んでください。具体的な処理は外部の決済処理に依存するのでこれ以上はわかりません。

Comment: 度々答えていただいてありがとうございます。